# In PHP, how to convert to regular time format from a number

Tags: php, time

I inherited a database that stores the times as 900 for 9:00am and 1500 for 3:00pm.  How can I convert these numbers to normal time formats in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PHP `mktime()` function. So you would do something like this:

```
$hour = substr($time, 0, -2); // Get everything before last two chars of string
$minute = substr($time, -2); // Gets last two chars of string
$newtime = mktime($hour, $minute);
```

Then use PHP `date()` to format it how you want.

Comment: Thanks, added a echo date('g:i', $newtime); and all is well, thanks!